# Adding to model with OneToMany and updating existing entries.

Tags: django, django-models

I have a couple of Django model questions.  I am running the following code as a Django manage extension, which I am new to.

1) I am not certain my "Location.objects.get(city=key)" is correct for OneToMany in my ***add_server_to_db*** function.  I suspect this is incorrect?

2) How can I harden this so if this is executed twice, it will update existing ***Server*** entries vs. error out?

**Django Server Model:**

```
class Servers(models.Model):
    name       = models.CharField(('name'), max_length=128)
    location   = models.OneToOneField('locations.Location', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ip_address = models.CharField(('ip_address'), max_length=128)
    date       = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

**Django Location Model:**

```
class Location(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(('city'), max_length=10)
    geolocation = models.PointField(('location'))
```

**Function:**

```
def add_server_to_db(data_dict):
    print(data_dict)
    for key, val in data_dict.items():
        loc = Location.objects.get(city=key)
        m = Server(
             location=loc,
             name=val['name'],
             ip_address=val['ip_address'],
        m.save()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your question 1; there's nothing wrong with that line, and nothing specific to "one-to-many" in any case.

To prevent this creating new entries every time, you should use [`update_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create):

```
loc = Location.objects.get(city=key)
Server.objects.update_or_create(
     location=loc,
     defaults={'name': val['name'], 'ip_address': val['ip_address']}
)
```

There's no need to call `save()` after this.